# How to ssh from one host to another host using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I have a situation where I need to, using robot framework, ssh to host1 and then to host2 from my local mac machine, as there is no route to host2 directly. I tried opening second connection after opening the first connection but this didn't work.

```
Test nested ssh connections
    Open Connection     ${host1}
    Login               ${host1-user}      ${host1-pw}
    ${output}=          Execute Command     hostname
    log to console      ${\n}${output}
    Open Connection     ${host2}    #there is no pw
    ${output}=          Execute Command     hostname
    log to console      ${\n}${output}

output:

Open Connection And Log In                                ...
host1
 14:17:59 up 44 days, 18:13,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Open Connection And Log In                                | FAIL |
Connection not open
```

Ican't figure out why second connection doesn't open. Is there a solution to this problem?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After opening connection to first host, you can simply use **Write, Read, Read Until** keywords to login to second host.
The keyword will look something like: (you can use variables, I am using hardcoded values for ip, username, password)

```
Test nested ssh connections
    Open Connection     ${host1}
    Login               ${host1-user}      ${host1-pw}
    Write    ssh user@10.10.0.23
    Read Until    password:
    Write    user123
    Read Until    $
```

Comment: Thank you @Sushanta Das, that is a very elegant solution to my problem and it works nicely. Totally forgot about Write and Read Until keywords.